# Block myself from running a game for too long or after late hours

Tags: windows, game, productivity, parental-control

I used to be addicted to WoW and I healed myself by using the parental controls to block at one 30-minute slot every 4 hours. It was great.

I have a new game addiction now, on Steam, and it turns out Steam has no parental controls. Boo.

Here's my wishlist:

- I don't want to be able to play the game between 12:30 AM and 8:30 AM.
- I don't want to be able to play the game for longer than 3 hours without a short (but not too short) break.

I play single-player, so network blocking is ineffective.

I prefer if I'm able to block only the target executable, but a system-wide block is an acceptable workaround.

Vaguely related: [Block self from reopening timewasting sites for X minutes after they were closed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31422)

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: @Peter Windows 10.

Comment: Steam has a "family mode" that restricts access to certain games or features, but I don't think its able to block based on time of day or duration of play. I found a link to https://getcoldturkey.com in a year old reddit discussing this. It looks like it fits the bill, but its not free.

Comment: @trooper The price isn't bad. I may actually buy it. The addiction is costing me more than that in subjective ways.